# How to implement XMPP and Sqlite in Xamarin?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xmpp, cross-platform, portable-class-library

I am working on a project in Xamarin where i want to use MatriX and SQLite.Net.Cipher libraries. I want to implement the app for Android, iOS and WindowsPhone. As far I understand I have to use a Shared Project for MatriX and a PCL Project for SQL. 
How can I get it work together? Or am I wrong that I need a PCL for SQL.

Comment: Have you tried using SQL in a Shared Project and see what happens? Sometimes a 5 minute experiment is all you really need.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work. I was confused because of the name. I thought the library is just and only for PCL projects.